# Running Tomcat server with SSL certificate triggers could not find or load main class cert.pkcs12

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl

I've been following this guide to setup SSL certificate on my Tomcat server. 
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29585_01/PlatformServices.61x/security/src/tsec_ssl_jsp_pkcs12.html

When I try to run the .bat file with there mentioned parameters (with my pwd):

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=PKCS12 
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=%CLIENT_CERT% 
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=endeca 
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=%CLIENT_CERT% 
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=endeca
```

I get this error at the startup:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Files\Java\jre7\lib\security\cert.pkcs12
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have java installed in `Programm Files` ? May be the space in the path is causing the issue!

Comment: Great! I add it as an answer. Plz accept it, it can be helpful for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is caused by the space in java installation path `C:\Program Files\Java`. Install java into a path without spaces will resolve the issue.

**Update**

Add quotes around the path solve also the issue. Thanks @Ondrej

Comment: Actually better solution is to add quotes around the cert file path definition.